# .NET 6 EF Core Power Tools migration -> No database provider has been configured for this DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I would like to read my ConnectionString from appsettings.json which i will later outsource to CICD pipeline. But....

I've set up an class library project in .NET 6.0 (**No** ASPNET or Webproject) only a blank class library project and generated me via EF Core my DBContext and "table"-classes with configuration in their own files.

For the first run i generated the connection string inside the "**OnConfiguring**" method of my "**MyDBContext**" class. The class looks like

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
    {
    }

    public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Table1> TABLE1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         /*optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=MySQLServer; Initial Catalog...etc");*/
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "Latin1_General_CI_AS");

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Configurations.Table1Configurations);

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

So the "OnConfiguring" method uses my connection string and it works perfectly fine when iam trying to use the migration tool from EF Core PowerTool.

Now i would like to outsource the "optionsBuilder.UseSQLServer", so that the DbContext is "only" a DBContext without knowledge of its connection.

For that i created the "appsettings.json" file and put my connection string in it.
And outcommented the "optionsBuilder" in the "OnConfiguring" method of my DbContext.

```
{"ConnectionString":{"MyDBConnectionString": "Data Source=MySQLServer Initial...etc"}}
```

Okay i have to read now from the appsettings.json file. Should be fine.
Setting up a "Program.cs"

```
public static class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
      .Build();

     /*    WHAT AM I MISSING */
     ConfigureServices(/*WhereToGetServicesFrom*/, Configuration)
   }

   public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration    configuration)
   {
      services.AddDBContext<MyDBContext>(options => 
          options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBConnection")));
   }
}
```

This should work if i can call the "ConfigureServices" method, but because i have no ASP project, i am missing the services.

If iam now calling the Migration Tool over EF Core Power Tools iam still getting the error "No database provider has been configured for this DBContext".

Iam totally brain afk right now.

If anyone can push me in the right direction this would be an pleasure

Greetings A7GPS0

Comment: Note that Entity Framework 6 (in your tags) is a previous iteration of EF for .NET Framework.

Comment: `GetConnectionString("")` looks suspect; I'd expect a connstr name in the `""` like `"MyDBConnectionString"`. Also, I think the json section should be ConnectionString**s** plural

Comment: @CaiusJard i've updated. Yes you are right i missed here in the code section the connstr name inside the GetConnectionString(). My original code has it. But "GetConnectionString() is right, not "...String*s*"

Comment: So my actual problem is that i have to call the method ConfigureServices. 
I can pass this method the "Configuration" the IConfiguration parameter, but then i still miss the services.

Comment: Oh.. I missed the part where you said it's a DLL..